# SwiftUI Picker selection binding not updating

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui

I am trying to have a picker list all of a type, called `Course` and then let the user select the appropriate course when adding a new `Assignment` to the managed object context. The picker selection binding (`courseIndex`) isn't updated when the user taps a row in the picker view. I'm not entirely sure how to fix the issue, nor do I know what is causing it. Any help is appreciated!

Here is the affected code:

```
struct NewAssignmentView: View {

@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context
@FetchRequest(entity: Course.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Course.name, ascending: true)]) var courses: FetchedResults<Course>

@State var name = ""
@State var hasDueDate = false
@State var dueDate = Date()
@State var courseIndex = 0


var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        Form {
            TextField("Assignment Name", text: $name)
            Section {
                Picker(selection: $courseIndex, label:
                    HStack {
                        Text("Course: ")
                        Spacer()
                        Text(self.courses[self.courseIndex].name ?? "").foregroundColor(self.courses[self.courseIndex].color).bold()
                    })
                {
                    ForEach(self.courses, id: \.self) { course in
                        Text("\(course.name ?? "")").foregroundColor(course.color).tag(course)
                    }
                }
            }
            Section {
                Toggle(isOn: $hasDueDate.animation()) {
                    Text("Due Date")
                }
                if hasDueDate {
                    DatePicker(selection: $dueDate, displayedComponents: .date, label: { Text("Set Date:") })
                }
            }
        }
[...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot make your snapshot compilable, so just changed, here... I assume that as your selection is index, you have to use ranged `ForEach` instead, like

```
ForEach(0 ..< self.courses.count) { i in
    Text("\(self.courses[i].name ?? "")").foregroundColor(self.courses[i].color).tag(i)
}
```

PS. not sure about `tag` usage, probably it might be not needed.

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 39):

When using optional binding values it's important that you explicitly provide the optional wrapping for the tag values because Swift doesn't automatically unwrap it for you and fails to equate a non-optional value with an optional one.

```swift
@Binding var optional: String?

Picker("Field", selection: $optional) {
    // None option.
    Text("None").tag(String?.none)
    // Other fields.
    ForEach(options) { option in
        Text(option).tag(String?.some(option))
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I needed to read!  Thank you!!

Comment: This works, thank you! The fact that simply `.tag(option)` does not work seems ridiculous but SwiftUI works in mysterious ways.

Comment: Amazing! I bumped my head at the wall for a whole day

Comment: 2 years later and this was biting me. Brilliant!

Comment: It works, but it's more straightforward to write `.tag(option as String?)`

Comment: for object just do `Text(object.name).tag(object ?? nil)`. Does not make sense but work. After  hours of fighting with the bug.