# Picker not updating selection binding for Realm entities

Tags: swift, swiftui, realm

I have a view that passes a binding to another view which includes a `Picker`. When an item is selected in the picker, the binding is not updated.

Here is the parent view:

```
struct AccountsView: View {
    
    @SceneStorage("selectedAccount") private var selectedAccount: String?
    @SceneStorage("isAddingAccount") private var isAddingAccount: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            AccountsToolbar(selection: selectedAccountId, isAddingAccount: $isAddingAccount)
            if isAddingAccount {
                CreateAccountView(isAddingAccount: $isAddingAccount)
            }
        }
        .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .topLeading)
    }
    
    var selectedAccountId: Binding<ObjectId?> {
        Binding(
            get: { selectedAccount == nil ? nil : try? ObjectId(string: selectedAccount!) },
            set: { print("new id: \($0)"); selectedAccount = String(describing: $0) }
        )
    }
    
}
```

...and the child view:

```
struct AccountsToolbar: View {
    
    @Binding var selection: ObjectId?
    @Binding var isAddingAccount: Bool
    @ObservedResults(Account.self) var accounts

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Picker("Account", selection: $selection) {
                ForEach(accounts, id: \.self) { account in
                    Text(account.name).tag(account._id)
                }
            }
            Button {
                isAddingAccount = true
            }
        label: {
            Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                .resizable()
                .foregroundStyle(.white, .indigo)
                .symbolRenderingMode(.palette)
                .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
        }
        .buttonStyle(.borderless)
        }
        .frame(height: 64)
    }
}
```

The Realm model looks like this:

```
class Account: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable {

    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: ObjectId
    @Persisted var name: String
    @Persisted var apiKey: String
    @Persisted var privateKey: String

}
```

As I say, when an item is chosen from the `Picker`, the binding is not updated. The `print` in the `set:` of the binding in the `AccountsView` prints `nil`.

I have tried:

- conforming the model to the `Identifiable` protocol
- using a `String?` binding, rather than an `ObjectId?` binding
- using `Text(...).id(...)` rather than `Text(...).tag(...)`
- eliding the `\.self` in the `ForEach`

What might I be missing/doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59277070/swiftui-picker-selection-binding-not-updating)

I changed my `Picker` binding:

```
@Binding var selection: String?
...
Picker("Account", selection: $selection) {
    ForEach(accounts) { account in
        Text(account.name).tag(String?.some(String(describing: account._id)))
    }
}
```

It seems to work!